# ExtJs Add empty value to combobox which is loaded remotely?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I there any way to add an empty value to combobox which is loaded remotely?

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    emptyText: 'Proveedor...',
    store: 'MyStore',
    displayField: 'title',
    valueField: 'mymodel_id',
    queryMode: 'remote',
    typeAhead: true
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listen to the `load` event of the store for the combobox, and insert an empty record in the handler:

```
Ext.getStore('MyStore').on('load', function(store) {
    store.insert(0, Ext.create('MyModel', {
        mymodel_id: -1,                  // some invalid id
        title: 'Choose from the list...' // default text for the empty record
    });
});
```